# Moving existing Zend Action Controllers into a module

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller

I began developing an administrative Zend PHP application but was informed later into the project that the same application needs to support a public facing interface. I would like to move my current controllers and views into a separate module and am unsure of the best way to approach this.

If I simply generate the module using zf create and copy all of my assets into the new module and attempt to navigate to any of those actions within the module Zend can't seem to find them as it throws the following error:

```
Next exception 'Zend_Controller_Exception' with message 'Invalid controller specified (error)#0 /opt/zf/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 /opt/zf/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 /opt/z in /opt/zf/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php on line 336
```

My only guess is that I'm breaking the default routes that Zend sets up for new controllers using zf create but am very new to Zend and have been unable to find any information on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prefix your controller with the module name: `{ModuleName}_{ControllerName}Controller` (if this isn't your default module). The filename remains the same however. The `.zfproject.xml` doesn't influence your application. This file only contains information for the zf-tool.

Comment: Actually realized this after using the zf-tool to generate fresh controllers instead of just copying the scripts. I feel pretty stupid it took that to make me remember the pseudo namespacing stuff... otherwise you could have naming conflicts between module controllers. Also, I had a feeling that the `.zfproject.xml` was only for the zf-tool but thanks for the confirmation.